# Entity Framework 4.1 Relationships and Inserts?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have an Entity Framework model that has 3 tables (each with indentity primary keys).  The root table has a 1 to many relationship to a child table, that child table has a 1 to many relationship with it's child table. This model is reflected correctly in the model that was generated from the database.

In code, we do an Insert (Add) into the parent table, we then do an insert of that children's tables, and then finally we do inserts on the children's children.  The code looks similar to the example below:

```
foreach(var parentItemDTO in someDTOCollection) {
    foreach(var someChildDTOItem in someChildDTOCollection) {
        // Do some mapping here to the childEntity from DTO
        // The foreign key relationship isn't set during mapping.

        childTable.Insert(childEntity); // Underlying code is _dbSet.Add(entity)

        foreach(var someChildChildDTOItem in someDTOChildChildCollection) {
            // Do some mapping here to childChildEntity from DTO
            // The foreign key relationship isn't set during mapping.

            childChildTable.Insert(childChildEntity);   // Underlying code is _dbSet.Add(entity)
        } 
    }

    // Do mapping here of the parentEntity from DTO

    parentTable.Insert(someEntity);  // Underlying code is _dbSet.Add(entity)
}
```

The inserts into the database seem to be working.  However, what I would like to understand is under the hood how does EF maintain the relationship of these objects without me explicitly defining the foreign key relationship during the mapping?  Is these inserts scope safe?  Will this cause orphans or children being inserted into the wrong parent (right now we don't see this happening but does it have the potential)?

Thanks!

**EDITED (CORRECTION):**

The code has been updated to reflect that the parent insert is happening AFTER all the children inserts.

Comment: Oh, Sean, actual inserts don't happen until you call SaveChanges(). When you add an object to DbSet EF just starts to keep track of it in memory, only when you save ALL entities will be written to the database. At this point EF will figure out that parent entity needs to be saved first, than will use its PK to as FK in your child entities. Is that what you were wondering about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the entities to be tracked properly by EF you need to have properties that represent relationships between entities. You parent entity should have a property referencing children and children in turn should have properties referencing their children. For example:

```
class ParentEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
}

class ChildEntity { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

As long as you add child entities to parent's Children collection EF can keep track of relationships:

```
var parent = new ParentEntity();
parent.Children.Add(new ChildEntity());
parent.Children.Add(new ChildEntity());
```

EF knows that object references in parent.Children collection represent new entities (entities not attached to the context) and will handle them accordingly. The actual inserts to the database don't happen until you call SaveChanges(). When you add an object to DbSet EF just begins to keep track of it in memory. Only when you call SaveChanges() entities will be written to the database. At this point EF will figure out that parent entity needs to be saved first. It will then use parent entity's PK as FK in your child entities. Now you can add parent to context and this will also add children:

```
context.Set<ParentEntity>().Add(parent);
context.SaveChanges(); // adds parent and two children.
```

Comment: The POCOs do have collections defined in them and the children do have the parent entity defined in them as well.  However, second part isn't happening in our code (the last part is), but our child entities are still being properly inserted with the parent primary key as the foreign key in the children tables.  There has to be something else going on here that we're missing?  Something going on under the hood?  NOTE: Updated code to reflect that insert of parent is happening after insert of children (this is in a context.DbSet<T>).

Comment: If you add child entity to parent's collection, or set child's parent reference to parent entity EF can figure you the relationships. When you save the parent it will follow .net object references and discover all dependent entities and insert them properly.

Comment: Okay.  This explains it!  Thanks.